# Proof of increasing positive valued function

Tags: probability, chebyshev-function

> Let $g$ be a monotonically increasing positive valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\mathbb{P}(X\geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]}{g(a)}$.

-I've tried expanding $\mathbb{E}[g(x)]$ using Taylor series as $g(\mu) + 0.5g^{\prime\prime}(\mu)\sigma^2$...don't know if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ is increasing and positive, we have
$$ g(a)1_{X\geq a}\leq g(X)$$
and the result follows by taking the expected value of both sides.

Comment: Okay but I'm confused on getting the expected value of g(X), is it the same normal formula of integrating (x* g(x)) dx?

Comment: In general $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int_{\Omega}g(X)\;d\mathbb{P}$. If $X$ has a pdf $f$, then $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x)\;dx$.

Comment: yeah thats what's confusing me, we werent given a pdf of f

Comment: Well the answer is in terms of $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$, is it not? So it's not necessary to compute it to solve the problem.

Comment: hmm okay, but why do we need to take the expected value of both sides?  should it not be just the expected value of g(X)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused on why we need to take the expected value of both sides @carmichael561

Comment: Well $\mathbb{E}[1_{X\geq a}]=\mathbb{P}(X\geq a)$, so taking the expected value of both sides immediately yields the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Let start with the decomposition
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] =\mathbb{E}[g(X)| X \leq a]P(X \leq a) +  \mathbb{E}[g(X)|X > a]P(X>a).$$

First, since $g$ is always positive, we get
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X \leq a] \geq 0$$

Second, since $g$ monotonically increasing, $X > a \Rightarrow g(X) \geq g(a)$, then
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)| X > a] \geq g(a)$$

With this two results, we can easily find that
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] \geq g(a)P(X>a).$$